# My example app works with adding/viewing data but data not visible in Firestore console

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

To understand Flutter & Firestore I have used the code from https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/using-firebases-cloud-firestore-in-flutter-79a79ec5303a. The app in a Pixel 2 simulator works as expected ie adding and displaying Tasks. I created a linked to my Firestore database but Tasks added are not being shown in Firestore Data. Any data I add directly in Firestore is not being shown in the app. The obvious conclusion is that I am looking at the wrong Firestore database. But it is from this database I copied the google-services.json and the database Usage relates to when I use the app. What approach can I use to debug this?

The google-services.json firebase_url (line 4) takes me to the firebase - Database - Realtime Database. But the Realtime database displays no data. I then select from the pull-down Firestore (but still no data displayed). I disabled the Realtime database. App works as expected. Displays Tasks stored from previous sessions and I can add new ones. Still can't see any stored data anywhere!!

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to solve my problem by deleting the Pixel 2 emulator and creating a completely new one.

Comment: This does not make sense at all... Maybe in that emulator was a google-services.json that was not yours, you thought you were building from your source but you weren't.

Comment: Possibly. You are right it doesn't make sense. I was wondering if it could be something to do with the emulator thinking it was off-line so storing data locally. For some reason the usage was still getting back to Firebase???

Comment: In my case, it was a VPN issue :facepalm: 
Firebase bans my country.

Comment: I have the same problem, data seems to be stored somewhere but not in firebase console!